# ASP.NET MVC / Get raw value from query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, system.web

How can I get the raw value corresponding to a parameter from a query string in ASP.NET MVC (5.2.7) ?

Currently, I am only able to get the decoded value.
For example, with the query string `p=lol%20cat`, the code below returns "lol cat" :

```
string decoded = Request.QueryString["p"]; // "lol cat"
```

When my query string is `p=lol%20cat`, I want to get "lol%20cat".
Also, if it is `p=lol+cat`, I want to get "lol+cat".

I could build something myself using `System.Web.HttpRequestBase` or `System.Uri` but I would prefer to use something reliable, built-in the .NET Framework.

Comment: simply you cant you must pass two value or one value without spaces

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
Request.Url.Query
```

This returns the raw querystring as a string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I have to search in the string (split, etc) myself. Sure, I can do it but I don't want to reinvent the wheel and it would be better if something like `Request.EncodedQueryString["p"]` exists.